# Creating membership list with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library

I had a foreach loop which used to loop Membership users and create list of a custom class. Following was the for loop:

> ```
> foreach (MembershipUser usr in userlist)
> {
>     userandGroup usrgp = new userandGroup();
>     usrgp.id = ((Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey).ToString() ;
>     usrgp.Name = usr.UserName;
>     ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(usr.UserName);
>     profile.Initialize(usr.UserName, true);
>     // Following line takes approx 40ms to execute once.
>     usrgp.DisplayName = profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString() + " " + profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString();
>     usrgp.type = "user";
>     lst.Add(usrgp);
> }
> ```

As the commented line used to take approx 40ms to execute, the whole loop for 40 users used to take approx 1600ms to execute.

I got suggestion to use Parallel.ForEach loop to reduce the execution time of the loop from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806353/how-to-reduce-the-execution-time-profilebases-getpropertyvalue-takes-40ms-to-e)

SO I updated the loop as:

```
    Object obj = new Object();
    Parallel.ForEach(userlist, (usr) =>
    {
        userandGroup usrgp = new userandGroup();
        usrgp.id = ((Guid)usr.ProviderUserKey).ToString();
        usrgp.Name = usr.UserName;
        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(usr.UserName);
        profile.Initialize(usr.UserName, true);
        usrgp.type = "user";
        usrgp.DisplayName = profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName").ToString() + " " + profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName").ToString();
        lock (obj)
        {                
            lst.Add(usrgp);
        }
    });
```

The loop works. Now the performance is way better (Although not best). It now takes only 700ms to execute the loop.

But I am not sure if it is the correct way to write Parallel.ForEach loop as I am new to it. Kindly suggest if the code is right?

Comment: It'd be much better if you could post the complete method and not just the  the `Parallel.ForEach` loop because e.g. the `lst` is not defined here so we don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going parallel I'd first try to understand which part of that code is slow. Maybe there is something you can do which will boost performance even more. That said I have few notes:

- `userandGroup` does not follow naming conventions, types should be PascalCase.
- There is no benefit to abbreviate names to `usrgp` and `obj`. is `usrgrp` a...group? Call it `group` (or `userGroup` if owner isn't clear from context). `obj` says what it is (an object), not what it does (the object which is used as synchronisation context). You may rename it (at least) to `syncRoot` (name used also in the framework itself for this purpose).
- If `lst` is local then you do not need `obj` and you can directly lock on it.
- You do not need to cast `ProviderUserKey` to `Guid` to call `ToString()`: `usr.ProviderUserKey.ToString()` or (if `ProviderUserKey` is `object` and it might be `null`) maybe `Convert.ToString(usr.ProviderUserKey)`.
- Object initialisation may be simplified:

Using Object Initialization syntax:

```
var group =  new userandGroup
{
    id = usr.ProviderUserKey.ToString(),
    Name = usr.UserName
};
```

Follow naming convention also here, `id` should be `Id`. Also move `Profile` creation before `group` and you can initialise everything in this way.

- `DisplayName` initialisation may use string interpolation:

As before:

```
DisplayName = $"{profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName")} {profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName")}"
```

- If `FirstName` or `LastName` may be empty then you're adding a spurious space. Handle the case (or at least add a call to `Trim()`.)
- `true` boolean parameters are a pain, I see the call and I need to go to check the prototype to know what it means. More than that: if I need another option then I need to add more and more parameters.

Use named parameters if you can't change the prototype (name is fictional in this case):

```
profile.Initialize(usr.UserName, loadUserProfile: true);
```

Or, better, use an `enum` with the `[Flags]` attribute to make clear - at calling point - what parameter means.

- You initialised `Profile` with the user name as parameter in its ctor, do you need it again here?
- If `lst` is local then you can simplify your code.

Move the logic to create `group` into a separate function (basically all the code you have inside the parallel loop) then:

```
var groups = userlist.AsParallel()
    .Select(CreateGroup)
    .ToList();
```

Where `CreateGroup` is something like this (note that I moved the hard-coded `user` string to a constant defined elsewhere and I moved the possibly complex logic for `DisplayName` to a separate function):

```
UserAndGroup CreateGroup(MembershipUser user)
{
    var profile = new Profile(user.UserName);
    profile.Initialize(user.UserName, true);

    return new UserAndGroup
    {
        Id = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(),
        Name = user.UserName,
        Type = UserGroupType,
        DisplayName = ResolveDisplayName()
    };

    string ResolveDisplayName()
        => $"{profile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName")} {profile.GetPropertyValue("LastName")}";
}
```